# jest.mock/jest.spyOn not mocking imported library

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm abstracting away some logic in accessing the AWS Cognito SDK library (amazon-cognito-identity) in a nodejs project (Lambda).  I'm having problems with mocking in unit tests.  Specifically when I try to mock the library classes (e.g., CognitoUserPool below), the *original* module is called (it calls the original library constructor for CognitoUserPool).

Edit: Corrected wrongly copy/pasted code.

My test file:

```
const { CognitoUserPool } = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

const mockUpdateAttributes = jest.fn();
const mockGetUserAttributes = jest.fn();

jest.mock('amazon-cognito-identity-js', () => 
    ({
        CognitoUserPool: jest.fn(() => ({
            signUp: jest.fn(),
        })),
    })
);

require('dotenv').config();
const awsUserPool = require('../../src/shared/awsUserPool.js');

describe('awsUserPool', () => {
    describe('getUserPool', () => {
        it ('should return a user pool', () => {
            const pool = awsUserPool.getUserPool();

            expect(CongnitoUserPool).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
                ClientId: 'TEST_APP_CLIENT_ID',
                UserPoolId: 'TEST_USER_POOL_ID',
            });
        })
    });
});
```

In awsUserPool.js:

```
const { CognitoUserPool, CognitoUserAttribute, CognitoUser } = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

const getUserPool = () => {
    var poolData = {
        "UserPoolId": process.env['COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID'],
        "ClientId": process.env['COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID'],
    };

    return new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the original module is called? What error are you seeing? When I run the code, the error is `ReferenceError: CongnitoUserPool is not defined` because of a typo in your sample.

Here's a minimal file where I define everything in the same file, and it works as long as the typo in the provided code is corrected:

```js
const { CognitoUserPool } = require('amazon-cognito-identity-js');

const getUserPool = () => {
    var poolData = {
        "UserPoolId": 'TEST_USER_POOL_ID',
        "ClientId": 'TEST_APP_CLIENT_ID',
    };

    return new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
}

jest.mock('amazon-cognito-identity-js', () => 
    ({
        CognitoUserPool: jest.fn(() => ({
            signUp: jest.fn(),
        })),
    })
);

describe('awsUserPool', () => {
    describe('getUserPool', () => {
        it ('should return a user pool', () => {
            const pool = getUserPool();

            // !!!!   The typo was "Cong"nitoUserPool   !!!!
            expect(CognitoUserPool).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
                ClientId: 'TEST_APP_CLIENT_ID',
                UserPoolId: 'TEST_USER_POOL_ID',
            });
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Yea, in my clean up of my actual code I inadvertently removed the require.  The error I get is that CognitoUserPool is never called: 

`awsUserPool > getUserPool > should return a user pool`
`Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)`
`Expected: {"ClientId": "TEST_APP_CLIENT_ID", "UserPoolId": "TEST_USER_POOL_ID"}`
`Number of calls: 0`

Comment: Ah, hmm that's unfortunate. If you copy my minimal working code, does this test pass for you? If it doesn't then I would think it's a jest.config or jestsetup problem.

Comment: So it looks like this might be a PopOS/Windows issue.  I pulled my repo on my windows machine and was able to finish writing my test cases.  I then pushed my changes, pulled them down to my PopOS lappy - and the mocking isn't working here...

Comment: That's an odd thing, but glad that's sorted. Ideally OSes use the standard implementation for web frameworks, but it's possible that PopOS doesn't.